yarn build Error - Module parse failed: Unexpected token
I ran yarn build as usual, but I encountered the following error:
./node_modules/@mui/base/unstable_useModal/useModal.js 107:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (107:28)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   }, [open, handleClose, hasTransition, closeAfterTransition, handleOpen]);
|   const createHandleKeyDown = otherHandlers => event => {
>     otherHandlers.onKeyDown?.(event);
|
|     // The handler doesn't take event.defaultPrevented into account:

I didn't install any additional libraries before running the build, and I ran yarn install --ignore-engines (this isn't the first time I used --ignore-engines, I’ve used the same option for builds before). Could you suggest a potential solution?
What I tried:

added options in the babel config file
plugins: [
                  require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining')

exclude: /node_modules/,



module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    **exclude: /node_modules/,**          
  use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
        options: {
          presets: [["react-app", { flow: false, typescript: true }]],
          **plugins: [
                  require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining')**
          ],
        },
      },
      require.resolve("react-docgen-typescript-loader"),
    ],
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
  return config;
};

It didn't work.

This question is similar to: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:19). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
